# Is an arbitrary linear combination of Gaussians a Mixture of Gaussians?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm trying to prove a result and one of my desired lemmas states that a Linear Combination of Homoscedastic Gaussians can be seen as a Mixture of Gaussians, i.e., let $h = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i \mathcal{N}(\mu_i,\sigma)$, therefore, there exists $\nu_i$ such that

$$ h = \sum_{i=1}^{m} \mathcal{N}(\nu_i,\sigma) $$

The result is trivially true for $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{N}$. Does it holds for $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{R}$?

Further questions can be formulated:

1) Does the result holds in any arbitrary dimension?
2) Does the result holds for arbitrary $\sigma_i$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is $a_i$? ${}{}{}$

Comment: Sorry, those are the scalars of the linear combination. I have already edited it.